# How to split variables in batch files

Tags: variables, batch-file, cmd, split, ip

I need to take an IP from a variable, and replace the last 3 digits. So I would need it to take %IPvariable% and remove the last three digits and save the first six as some other variable. Any help is much appreciated. :)

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Seems to me like he just didn't know where to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this on a command line for an example:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1-4 delims=." %G IN ("127.0.0.254") DO echo %G %H %I %J
```

In the batch file you will need to add an extra % in front of the variables (ie, %G --> %%G)

Once you have the IP broken into 4 pieces you can reassemble as you see fit.

Something like:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1-4 delims=." %G IN ("127.0.0.254") DO echo %G %H %I %J & set "var=%G.%H.%I" & echo %var%
```

You will of course replace the "127.0.0.254" hardcoded IP with your %IPvariable%.

See this for more details on FOR /F:  http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html

Answer (score 0):

Another way, if you're sure that's always the 3 last digits :

```
@echo off
Set "$ip=127.0.0.254"
set "$New=253"

set "$ipnew=%$ip:~0,-3%%$New%"

echo New IP = %$IpNew%
```

Answer (score 0):

This will change the last octet to `666` in a batch file.

```
for %%a in (%IPvariable%) do set IPvariable=%%~na.666
```